# Error with "content-MD5" on AWS s3 bucket

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating an application that sends a video file to an Amazon s3 bucket but can only send 1 video before having to re-upload the apk to the phone. The error being thrown has something to do with a "BadDigest" error on the service: "Amazon S3". Below is the output error.

```
11-08 23:56:33.805 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadDigest; Request ID: 3345945A95914871), S3 Extended Request ID: pSWjCNJ6sMOiFytjZr0PRn9rns3jFoMkECoI+lfXgF0agfQTY4CdvXlsYJbCBK9qYE/OoAkWTrY=
11-08 23:56:33.806 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:729)
11-08 23:56:33.806 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
11-08 23:56:33.806 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
11-08 23:56:33.806 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4625)
11-08 23:56:33.807 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1728)
11-08 23:56:33.807 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.uploadSinglePartAndWaitForCompletion(UploadTask.java:214)
11-08 23:56:33.807 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:88)
11-08 23:56:33.807 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:47)
11-08 23:56:33.807 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-08 23:56:33.808 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
11-08 23:56:33.808 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
11-08 23:56:33.808 26045-26045/org.----------.videorecorder_aws W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Please let me know if you need further information, this is a fairly time sensitive question.

EDIT 1
In response to donkon, here is the code that I am using to send my files to the server:

```
public void submitVideoToS3Bucket(){
    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());

    File directory = new File(getFilesDir(), "Reflex");
    final File CameraFile = new File(directory, "camera-temp.mp4");

    Date now = new Date();
    String videoName = now.toString().concat(".mp4").replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "");

    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, videoName, CameraFile);

    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            if (TransferState.COMPLETED == state) {
            }
            System.out.println("state change");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(
                int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    if (TransferState.COMPLETED == observer.getState()) {
        // Handle a completed upload.
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
        startActivity(cameraIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea, but you should post on the AWS forums also if you haven't already.  AWS support is also very good if you can afford it.

Comment: Can you provide code and a sample file to reproduce error? Which version of SDK are you using?

Comment: Is the content changing as you are uploading it?

Comment: @ChrisPollard Yes, there are different videos being recorded and sent to the s3 bucket.

Comment: @donkon I edited my post to show the code for sending my file to the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the content is changing as you are uploading it. Try using your code to upload a static file (I.e. a video that is done recording) and it should work.

Comment: When I change "public void submitVideoToS3Bucket()" to "public static ..." it no longer works. How can I change this so that it is uploading a static file?

Comment: The video has to be completely done recording and saved before you start to upload.