# MD-5 Checksum error when uploading a file to S3 from AWS lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Firstly I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179310/an-exception-the-content-md5-you-specified-did-not-match-what-we-received) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241147/error-with-content-md5-on-aws-s3-bucket), but my case is slightly different.

I get this error when I try to upload files over 11MB to S3 buckets from my AWS lambda function:
**An error occurred (BadDigest) when calling the PutObject operation (reached max retries: 4): The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.**

My lambda does only this:

- Get some contents from a URL
- Store these contents in a file-like string object
- Create an object in S3 bucket with these contents written

  ```
  some_huge_text_from_a_url = requests.get(url)
  contents = StringIO.StringIO()
  contents.write(some_huge_text_from_a_url)
  contents.seek(0)
  s3_client.put_object(Body=contents, Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key)
  ```

I generate and upload the file from the same thread, but I still get this error. I contacted AWS support about this, they're a little slow to respond. So I want to know what SO community has to say about this.

AWS support suggested that my file contents are changing after MD-5 checksum is calculated by the lambda. I don't see how it is possible in the above code.

Please tell me if I'm missing to see something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time and gaining lot of experience, I learned that the checksum mismatch was because I had been using wrong file encoding all along.

I'm no expert when it comes to file encodings but simply changing the encoding to `utf-8` caused this error to go away.